# How can I start a chat room with particular user?

Tags: discussion, chat, private-messaging

How can I start a chat room with a particular user?

The are some users who often come up in searches related to technologies I'm interested in.

How do I start chat with them?

Comment: This question is a quite non-specific. Are you trying to make your own chatroom?

Comment: yes Mark Potter

Comment: Now it is specific Mark ?

Comment: This is already answered, I don't have privileges to comment.[Check this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/236514/how-do-i-invite-a-user-to-chat)

Comment: Please be sure to post questions about the network itself on Meta.

Answer (score 1):

As of right now, there is no way to directly communicate over Stack Exchange in a private user-to-user manner. This has been discussed previously in [numerous](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/433) posts and it seems as if that feature will not be introduced any time soon.

Your best bet would be to comment underneath a specific answer and hope the person you're trying to contact receives and responds to that message.

Comment: but the thing is when i started a comment with a same person, stack overflow its self suggested me that don't chat in a comment create chat room. sorry your answer not helpful for me

Comment: After a little more searching around, I found the following: [link](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/) Keep in mind the conversations are public.

Comment: from where i can create a room, please have a look on my question

Comment: I've added two duplicates to the question that explain how to create and invite users to a chatroom.